# Why is one label updating quicker then the other?

Tags: macos, performance, applescript, swift2

I am making my own Spotify controller to learn how to interact with AppleScript and Swift (using Objective-C as a bridge) to make a bigger project later on. The only issue is the current progress time seems to update slightly faster then the time left.

This is what my application looks like:

[image]

The time on the left seems to update slightly faster then the time on the right, this means it is not accurate and can be bit strange to look at. How would I be able to fix this so both the progress time and time left update at the same time?

Here is  my code:

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Cocoa


class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var songProgress: NSProgressIndicator!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblCurrentProgress: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTrackLength: NSTextField!
    
    //let debugger = Debug(appName:"Spotify Menu", debugable: )
    
    var previousScript:String = ""
    var toggleScript:String = ""
    var nextScript:String = ""
    var statusScript:String = ""
    var artistScript:String = ""
    var songNameScript:String = ""
    var trackPosScript:String = ""
    var trackLengthScript:String = ""
    var trackIDscript:String = ""
    
    
    var trackName:String = "unknown"
    var artistName:String = "unknown"
    var playerStatus:String = "unknown"
    var trackID:String = "unknown"
    var playerPosistion:Double = -1.0
    var trackLength:Double = -1.0
    var percentThrough:Double = -1.0
    
    let timeFormatter = twoDiffrentTimes()
    
    
    func main()
    {
        
        getStatus()
        getSongName()
        getArtist()
        getTrackLength()
        getPlayerPos()
        getID()
        percentThrough = (playerPosistion/trackLength)*100
        
        if(playerStatus == "playing" && trackName != "unknown" && artistName != "unknown")
        {
            statusLabel.stringValue = "Spotify is currently playing the song \"\(trackName)\" by \"\(artistName)\""
        } else if(playerStatus == "paused"){
            statusLabel.stringValue = "Spotify is currently paused"
        } else if(playerStatus == "stopped") {
            statusLabel.stringValue = "Spotify is not playing any music"
        } else {
            statusLabel.stringValue = "There is currently an error"
        }
        
        //NSLog("The song is currently \(percentThrough.toDecimalPlace("2"))% the way in")
        songProgress.doubleValue = percentThrough
        
        timeFormatter.update(playerPosistion, timeTwo: trackLength-playerPosistion)
        lblCurrentProgress.stringValue = timeFormatter.timeOneString
        lblTrackLength.stringValue = timeFormatter.timeTwoString
    }
    

    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        previousScript = readFile("previousTrack")
        if(previousScript == "")
        {
            NSLog("Error finding previous track script")
            exit(1)
        }
        
        toggleScript = readFile("playPause")
        if(toggleScript == "")
        {
            NSLog("Error finding toggle script")
            exit(1)
        }
        
        nextScript = readFile("nextTrack")
        if(nextScript == "")
        {
            NSLog("Error going forwared a track")
            exit(1)
        }
        
        statusScript = readFile("playerStatus")
        if(statusScript == "")
        {
            NSLog("Error going back a track")
            statusLabel.stringValue = "Spotify is in an unknown status"
            exit(1)
        }
        
        artistScript = readFile("getArtist")
        if(artistScript == "")
        {
            NSLog("Cannot get artist script")
            exit(1)
        }
        
        songNameScript = readFile("getSongName")
        if(songNameScript == "")
        {
            NSLog("Cannot get song name script")
            exit(1)
        }
        
        trackPosScript = readFile("playerPosition")
        if(trackPosScript == "")
        {
            NSLog("Error getting track posistion script")
            exit(1)
        }
        
        trackLengthScript = readFile("durationOfSong")
        if(trackLengthScript == "")
        {
            NSLog("Error getting track length script")
            exit(1)
        }
        
        trackIDscript = readFile("trackID")
        if(trackIDscript == "")
        {
            NSLog("Error getting")
        }
        
        
        main()
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.3, target: self, selector: Selector("main"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    @IBAction func previous(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        runAppleScript(previousScript)
    }

    @IBAction func toggle(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        runAppleScript(toggleScript)
    }
    
    @IBAction func next(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let nextFile = readFile("nextTrack")
        if(nextFile == "")
        {
            NSLog("Error going forwared a track")
        } else {
            runAppleScript(nextFile)
        }
    }
    
    
    
    func getPlayerPos()
    {
        playerPosistion = runAppleScript(trackPosScript).toDouble()
    }
    
    func getTrackLength()
    {
        trackLength = runAppleScript(trackLengthScript).toDouble()
    }
    
    func getSongName()
    {
        trackName = runAppleScript(songNameScript)
    }
    
    func getArtist()
    {
            artistName = runAppleScript(artistScript)
    }
    
    func getID()
    {
        trackID = runAppleScript(trackIDscript)
    }
    
    func getStatus()
    {
        let resultData = runAppleScript(statusScript)
        if(resultData == "playing" || resultData == "paused" || resultData == "stopped")
        {
            playerStatus = resultData
        } else {
            playerStatus = "unknown"
        }
    }
    
}
```

**classes.swift**

```
import Foundation

class twoDiffrentTimes
{
    var timeOne:Double = 0.0
    var iMinuteOne:Int = 0
    var iSecondsOne:Int = 0
    var minuteOne:String = ""
    var secondsOne:String = ""
    var timeOneString:String = ""
    var uSecondsOne:Double = 0.0
    var temp:Int = 0
    
    var timeTwo:Double = 0.0
    var iMinuteTwo:Int = 0
    var iSecondsTwo:Int = 0
    var minuteTwo:String = ""
    var secondsTwo:String = ""
    var timeTwoString:String = ""
    var uSecondsTwo:Double = 0.0
    
    func update(timeOne:Double, timeTwo:Double)
    {
        //First Time
        self.temp = Int(timeOne)
        self.iMinuteOne = temp / 60
        self.iSecondsOne = temp % 60
        self.minuteOne = "\(iMinuteOne)"
        if(self.iSecondsOne < 10)
        {
            self.secondsOne = "0\(self.iSecondsOne)"
        } else {
            self.secondsOne = "\(self.iSecondsOne)"
        }
        self.timeOneString = "\(self.iMinuteOne).\(self.secondsOne)"

        
        //Second Time
        self.temp = Int(timeTwo)
        self.iMinuteTwo = temp / 60
        self.iSecondsTwo = temp % 60
        self.minuteTwo = "\(iMinuteTwo)"
        if(self.iSecondsTwo < 10)
        {
            self.secondsTwo = "0\(self.iSecondsTwo)"
        } else {
            self.secondsTwo = "\(self.iSecondsTwo)"
        }
        self.timeTwoString = "\(self.iMinuteTwo).\(self.secondsTwo)"

    }
}
```

**extensions.swift**

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    func toDouble() -> Double {
        if let unwrappedNum = Double(self) {
            return unwrappedNum
        } else {
            // Handle a bad number
            print("Error converting \"" + self + "\" to Double")
            return 0.0
        }
        
    }
    
}

extension Double {
    func toDecimalPlace(f: String) -> String {
        return NSString(format: "%0.\(f)f", self) as String
    }
    
    func decimalValue() -> Int
    {
        if let decimalString = String(self).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last, decimal = Int(decimalString) {
            return decimal   // 535
        } else {
            return -1
        }
    }
    
}
```

**functions.swift**

```
import Foundation

func readFile(fileName: String) -> String{
    
    if let filepath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "txt") {
        do {
            let contents = try NSString(contentsOfFile: filepath, usedEncoding: nil) as String
            print(contents)
            return contents
        } catch {
            NSLog("Content Could Not Be Loaded")
            return ""
        }
    } else {
        NSLog("File \(fileName).\("txt") could not be found")
        return ""
    }
}

func runAppleScript(script:String) -> String
{
    let theResult:String
    let errorInfo = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSDictionary?>()
    let startAtLoginScript: NSAppleScript = NSAppleScript(source: script)!
    let theDiscriptor:NSAppleEventDescriptor = startAtLoginScript.executeAndReturnError(errorInfo)
    if let _ = theDiscriptor.stringValue
    {
        theResult = theDiscriptor.stringValue!
    } else {
        theResult = ""
    }
    
    return theResult
}
```

**errorClases.swift**

```
import Foundation

enum MyAppleScriptError: ErrorType {
    case ExecutingScriptFailed
    case GettingStringValueFailed
}
```

Last but not least **durationOfSong.txt** (AppleScript)

```
tell application "Spotify"
    set songLength to (duration of current track) / 1000 as string
    return songLength
end tell
```

And **playerPosition**

```
tell application "Spotify"
    set currentPosistion to player position as string
    return currentPosistion
end tell
```

**Edit:**
Updated code

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow must be self contained; linking to your entire project is invalid.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Why can't we upload it to make make it easier for people to try the code out?

Comment: Because your question needs to remain useful past the expiry of that link. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266715/

Comment: @JoshCaswell It is still valid, I have put everything that is needed to debug the problem, I just put the file there so people don't need to make all the files and paste the code from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you learn how to call AppleScript handlers directly from Swift via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge. That will work vastly better than mucking about with code strings and `NSAppleScript`, which is slow and nasty and not a good way to do it. Tutorial here:

http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=43127

--

ETA:

"I have successful moved NSAppleScript to Swift2. Only thing is that still doesn't fix the issue. it is still out of timing."

Well, that's annoying. FWIW, I'd ditch that `twoDiffrntTimes` class as it doesn't do anything that can't be done in a single-line function, and change the end of `main()` to this:

```
func main() {
    ...

    lblCurrentProgress.stringValue = formatTime(Int(playerPosistion))
    lblTrackLength.stringValue = formatTime(Int(trackLength-playerPosistion))
}

func formatTime(secs: Int) -> String {
    return NSString(format: "%i.%02i", secs / 60, secs % 60) as String
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the objective-c bridge may be the problem due to performance then?

Comment: Also that website still uses objective-c. I have got this far `var errorInfo:NSDictionary` New Line `let scripter = NSAppleScript.init(source: "tell application \"Spotify\" to playpause")` New Line `scripter?.executeAndReturnError(errorInfo)`. However I can't seem to get the correct error variable type. In objective-c it was NSDictionary but doesn't work in swift

Comment: Constantly mashing AS code strings and compiling and executing them through `NSAppleScript` is not going to be fast. (Your time formatting code is also needlessly hokey and overwrought, but I don't see that affecting performance.)

Comment: "Also that website still uses objective-c." -- Because Swift isn't very dynamic, you still need a small amount of ObjC boilerplate to load and instantiate your AS 'classes', plus each AS 'class' needs a corresponding  ObjC protocol that declares the instance methods it provides. Once that's done, you can invoke their instance methods directly from Swift. It's a bit tedious to set up (though an enterprising user could easily write a command-line tool that generates this glue code automatically), but once it's done it's done, and the result is much less slow/painful to use than `NSAppleScript`.

Comment: BTW, in an ideal world you wouldn't need to do Swift-AS bridging at all. I've been working on a [Swift-to-Apple-Event-Manager bridge](https://bitbucket.org/hhas/swiftae) that'd allow Swift to control "AppleScriptable" apps *directly*, though it's not yet finished (I'm still deciding how best to bridge the different type systems) and I'm not interested in promoting to users it unless Apple can be persuaded to take it over and include it in 10.12. If you want to see high-quality automation support in Swift, feel free to ask Apple to adopt SwiftAE [via Radar](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: I have successful moved NSAppleScript to Swift2. Only thing is that still doesn't fix the issue. it is still out of timing.